# SQL query to get the data as of 31/03 of past three years

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the above query which give me the Bonus tagged to the person as of sysdate.

```
select 
    person_number ,
    peef.effective_start_Date,
    peef.value Amount
from 
    per_all_people_f papf,
    pay_element_entries_f peef
where 
    papf.person_id = peef.person_id
    and PEEF.element_name in ('Bonus')
    and sysdate between peef.effective_start_Date and peef.effective_end_Date
```

I want to tweak the above query to get the Amount for past three years as of 31/3 i.e. instead of sysdate as of 31/3/2021, 31/03/2020,31/03/2019

Output like -

```
Person_NUMBER   effective_start_Date      current_Amount            2021_AMOUNT         2020_AMOUNT         2019_AMOUNT
```

How can i tweak the same query and change the sysdate condition to look for data for past three years as well for the 2021_amount, 2020_amount and 2019_amount column

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What is the data type for effective_start_date and effective_end_date?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn- those are dates data type

Comment: You can add more conditions on dates via `OR`. What is the issue with it?

Comment: If i add it just via OR, I will not get the data in different respective columns right ?

Comment: `where` condition restricts the data returned, `select` list specifies expressions for output (i.e. which calculations should be returned in which output columns). I didn't understand the question correctly because the output structure is too "wide": I thought the issue was to select the data for 3 specific additional dates ("change the sysdate condition to look for data for past three years as well"), but looks like you need a `pivot`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the last line to the SELECT list as conditionals such as

```sql
SELECT person_number, peef.effective_start_Date, 
       peef.value AS current_amount,
       CASE WHEN date'2021-03-31' BETWEEN peef.effective_start_Date AND peef.effective_end_Date 
            THEN peef.value 
             END AS 2021_amount,
       CASE WHEN date'2020-03-31' BETWEEN peef.effective_start_Date AND peef.effective_end_Date 
            THEN peef.value 
             END AS 2020_amount,
       CASE WHEN date'2019-03-31' BETWEEN peef.effective_start_Date AND peef.effective_end_Date 
            THEN peef.value 
             END AS 2019_amount                          
  FROM per_all_people_f papf
  JOIN pay_element_entries_f peef
    ON peef.person_id = papf.person_id
 WHERE peef.element_name = 'Bonus'
```

in order to get the currently displayed result, but in this case there will be multiple lines with NULL values for amount columns. I suspect that you need to get aggregated results in order to show the summed up amounts, then consider adding SUM() aggregation such as

```sql
SELECT person_number, peef.effective_start_Date, 
       SUM( peef.value ) AS current_amount,
       SUM( CASE WHEN date'2021-03-31' BETWEEN peef.effective_start_Date AND peef.effective_end_Date 
                 THEN peef.value 
                  END ) AS 2021_amount,
       SUM( CASE WHEN date'2020-03-31' BETWEEN peef.effective_start_Date AND peef.effective_end_Date 
                 THEN peef.value 
                  END ) AS 2020_amount,
       SUM( CASE WHEN date'2019-03-31' BETWEEN peef.effective_start_Date AND peef.effective_end_Date 
                 THEN peef.value 
                  END ) AS 2019_amount                          
  FROM per_all_people_f papf
  JOIN pay_element_entries_f peef
    ON peef.person_id = papf.person_id
 WHERE peef.element_name = 'Bonus'
 GROUP BY person_number, peef.effective_start_Date
```

Comment: The case when date is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: I tried using this but this isnt working. It is throwing a syntax error in the case section

Comment: Hi @Sree , what error do you get?

Comment: As soon as I add the case, it throws ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected